# Roku TV code signing app without Roku box

Tags: roku

I'm a newbie on Roku development. I have a .zip package is installed on Roku box success.

Last time, I used browser to point to the [Roku box address to sign and package the app](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Packaging+Your+Application). But now I want to sign and package that zip without Roku box. Are there any way or lib support to do that?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* You just need to remove "or lib support" from your question. If there's a library to help you, people will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I *hate* seeing duplicate posts, cue https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=96285

You MUST have and use a Roku device to bundle your app. There is no other way. How do you imagine debugging and testing the app w/o a physical device?

On a side note, since your title is confusing - if you have RokuTV, you can use that too, does not have to be a Roku standalone "box"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I want to build the script that support to clone the app for my customers. The script will apply new resource(app content) and account info(sign and upload to their channel)  from different customer.